# how to reduce transaction fees on private blockchains?

Tags: solidity, gas, private-blockchain, sidechain

I have some questions regarding transaction fees on private blockchain.
I'd appreciate your help. Also, if there are any references I can read about this, please let me know.

1. Do transaction fees occur in private blockchains in the form of sidechains?
   maybe of course, but I was wondering if I could set the transaction fees for transfer/mint functions to be 0. But then, miners in my private blockchain would have no incentives, right?
2. I heard transaction fees are much lower in sidechains like Ronin, how is it possible? Is it simply because of less congestion?
3. I believe I can control/set transaction fees for transactions within my private blockchains, but for any transactions that require communications with mainnet, I cannnot control the transaction fess in any way, is it correct?
4. What ways are there to reduce the transaction fees in private blockchains?
   One idea i have is that if the entire network is owned by my organization or consortium meaning a permissioned network, and if we could all agree on a certain fee, then I guess we could fix the transaction fees low, right?
5. Can a consensus algorithm affect the transaction fees?

Answer (score 0):

In a private blockchain, you can use Quorum:

- there is no transaction fee in it
- it is almost identical to Ethereum in terms of smart contracts and in general
- there will be no forks in it
- it does not form blocks that do not contain transactions, which saves space
- it has a mechanism of protected private smart contracts (for example, Tessera)
- in general, it is more stable than Ethereum and is better suited for private networks with a relatively small number of nodes (up to 100)

Comment: that didn't answer my question. but thanks.